# How I can apply Inner Join to filter the data in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table in which I inserted all the liked places records. 
Like:
    I have table PlaceLikes;

```
 Id    placeId    likedByUserID
  1      ABC          1
  2      DEF          1
  3      ABC          2
  4      FFF          2
```

Result: User 1 want to get all placeID that matches with itself.

```
  Id    placeId    likedByUserID
  3      ABC          2
```

Here User 2 with ABC placeId is similar with Requestor User ID 1.
So, How I can filter the data like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where 
    t.likedByUserID <> 1
    and exists (
        select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.place_id = t.place_id and t1.likedByUserID = 1
    )
```

Comment: Thanks , This is working for me. Please let me know if we just call myTable once time rather than 2 times.

Comment: @AmandeepSingh: one way or another, you need two passes on the table. One to get the places liked by user 1, and another to get the records whose users liked the same places.

Answer (score 0):

I think this piece of query will be able to solve your problem statement as understood by  me.

```
DECLARE @sample_name VARCHAR (10);
SET @sample_name = 'placeId to be searched'
SELECT Id, placeId, likedByUserID FROM demo_table dt
WHERE dt.placeId = @sample_name
```

Do let me know if this was helpful.